# JQuery Cycle plugin- pager with thumbnails below the main images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

I am working on jQueryCycle plugin to get the pager with thumbnails below the main images. This is the tutorial I a working.
   http://digitalunion.osu.edu/2011/10/18/jquery-cycle-plugin-a-little-tutorial/

The below is my jQuery code I am working on

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
// dynamically add a div to hold the slideshow's pager
$(".bison_images").before('<div class="pager"></div>');

// now to use the cycle plugin
$(".bison_images").cycle({
    pause: 1,
    pager: ".pager",
    pagerAnchorBuilder: imagePager
}); 
 }

  function imagePager(index, slide) {
var slide = jQuery(slide);
var img = slide.children("img").get(0);
return '<a href="#"><img src="' + img.src + '" width="110" height="66" /></a>'; 
 }
```

Here I am getting the same output as shown in the example link, pasted above. But I want the pager below the main images. I tried it with the following command but there was no success.

```
 $(".bison_images").after('<div class="pager"></div>');
```

Can anyone suggest me the solution.

Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enter code here
```

Check this works...

```
 $('.bison_images').after('<div class="pager">').cycle({
            fx:     'scrollHorz',
            speed:  'slow',
            timeout: 9000,
            pager:  '.pager',
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
   var slide = jQuery(slide);
   var img = slide.children("img").get(0);
   return '<a href="#"><img src="' + img.src + '" width="110" height="66" /></a>';
}
        });
```